# Search Text By Value Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to get a Text GameObject by its value.
For example:
There's a lot of Texts and I only need the one that Says "Hello", NOT THE NAME, the value, i'ts content.

```
//PseudoCode
string = "Hello";
GameObject.FindObjectsByValue("Hello")
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in function for that, so you need to do it manually. It depends on your situation. In general you must:

1. Have reference to all GameObjects that might have that text value
2. Check each GameObject's text values with loop

If you need to look for that word ***once or twice*** then you can do something like this:

```
Text[] array = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Text>();

foreach (var x in array)
{
    if (string.Compare(x.text,"Hello") == 0)
    {
        // The stuff to do here
    }
}
```

If you need to keep looking for that ***word many times*** then you need store reference to those `GameObject`s in some variable and access it anytime you need. This is because `FindObjectsOfType<>();` is quite an expensive operation so we need to do it as little as possible. Something like this should work:

```
private Text[] array;

private void Awake()
{
    Text[] array = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Text>();
}
private void Update()
{
    foreach (var x in array)
    {
        if (string.Compare(x.text, "Hello") == 0)
        {
            // The stuff to do here
        }
    }
}
```